# $a_n$ and its alternating series $(-1)^n a_n$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I have 2 questions regarding series. 1. If $a_n >0$, and $\sum (-1)^n a_n$ converges, then does $\sum a_n$ converge? 2. (This one is unrelated to 1.) If $\sum a_n$ converges, then does $\sum (-1)^n a_n$ converge?

For 1., I doubt it. A counter example is $\sum (-1)^n \frac{1}{n}$, which converges, but $\sum \frac{1}{n}$ doesnt. 2. I'm not sure. If I make $a_n = \frac{sinx}{x} -2$, then does the series with $(-1)^n$ converge?

Comment: Write a title which has the potential of helping others in the future.

Comment: @zabop title changed.

Comment: In your second question, do we assume $a_n > 0$ again?  If not, your counterexample to your first question also provides a counterexample to the second.

Comment: Nope.  $(-1)^n a_n$ will bounce back and forth between positive negative values and if $a_n \to 0$ we can have the series trapped between bounds.  But $a_n$ can just grow without bound.  COnsider $\sum \frac 1k \to 0$.  But $\sum (-1)^k \frac 1k$ will have the fly being crushed by a train situation.

Comment: "I doubt it.  A counter example...."  If you have a counter example, why do you merely *doubt* it.  You should wave the counter example around you head and take to the streets shouting "NO!  A thousand times NO!  It is certainly without a doubt false! And a counter example nails it in a crypt to be false and dead forever!  Viva la countre-example!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first, take $ a_n=\frac 1n$.

$$\sum (-1)^na_n \text{ converges but}$$
$$\sum a_n \text{ diverges }$$

For the second, take $ b_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$.
$$\sum b_n \text{ converges but}$$
$$\sum (-1)^nb_n \text{ diverges }$$